# Determine $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(n!)!}$ conv or div?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, factorial

Determine $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\dfrac{1}{(n!)!}$ conv or div?

I tried applying the **root test** but I'm not sure how to evaluate this double factorial limit? Apparently it converges. I also don't know what other test I could apply?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} |\dfrac{((n+1)!)!}{(n!)!}|$$

Comment: This screams for comparison test.

Comment: But why would you think it converges?

Comment: compare with $\sum 1/n!$ which converges to $e$.

Comment: for all $n; \frac {1}{n!!} \le \frac {1}{n!}$

Comment: This converges extremely rapidly.

Comment: For an even more elementary comparison, note that $\frac{1}{(n!)!} < \frac{1}{2^n}$ for each $n \geq 3,$ and you know the latter converges from high school geometric series knowledge.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is completely trivial.

Comment: Hi, I notice that you tend to use `\dfrac` in your question titles a lot. Maybe you could consider avoiding `\dfrac` and using just `\frac` instead? Please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687) or [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18982), among other meta threads. Thanks.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm sorry, but trivialities are not off-topic. Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\dfrac{1}{(n!)!}<\dfrac{1}{n!}\qquad\forall\,n\ge2$$
(because $(n!)!=(n!)(n!-1)(n!-2)\cdots 2\cdot1>n!$ when $n\ge 2$)
where $\sum\dfrac{1}{n!}$ converges by the ratio test: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\vert\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right\vert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n+1}=0<1$$